# EmberJS. How use two way binding for input and focus event?

Tags: ember.js, binding

I'm trying to create custom input component. 
First of all I tried to use native input component. Somthing like this

```
<input type="text" value="{{inputValue}}" onblur={{action "toggleInputFocused"}} onfocus={{action "toggleInputFocused"}}>
```

But this code does't provide two way binding. The observer **valueChanged** doesn't triggered

```
valueChanged: Ember.observer('inputValue', function () {
  // deal with the change
  this.set("valueSet",(this.get('inputValue').trim().length > 0));
}),
```

Later I have try use input helper

```
{{input value=inputValue focus=(action "toggleInputFocused")}}
```

In this case valueChanged observer is triggered but focus event doesn't listening, otherwise the key-press is triggered.

How can I use two way binding and focus event at one time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `focus` built in event for ember. but there is `foucsIn` and `focusOut`.
For list of events https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.1.0/components/handling-events/#toc_event-names

```
{{input value=inputValue focus-in="toggleInputFocused"}}
```